# Черный экран после перезагрузки Windows 7 max

Tags: windows, amd, видеокарта, radeon, видеодрайвера

Играл я себе в игру, пару раз появлялся синий экран смерти, ну я сделал так чтобы убрать это, после всего этого загружает комп появился чёрный экран, ни курсора ничего, ну загрузил безопасный режим решил зайти в драйвера видеокарты MSI amd radeon r9 270, но выдавала вот это (Графический драйвер AMD не установлен или драйвер AMD не работает должным образом. Пожалуйста, установите драйвер AMD, соответствующий вашему оборудованию AMD). Ну я удалил драйвера в безопасном режиме, получилось зайти в нормальный режим, установил новые с официального, но после опять та же песня, черный экран. Переустановил винду думал конфликту винда с драйверами и все равно ни фига, после установки драйвера видеокарты опять перезагружаю и опять чёрный экран, помогите люди добрые!

Comment: Видимо у вас механическая проблема, возможно материнка "поехала" )) или же жёсткий диск, возможно(но редко) проблема с RAM. Необходимо аппаратное обследование в сервис центре

Comment: @Arsen *возможно материнка "поехала" )) или же жёсткий диск, возможно(но редко) проблема с RAM* То есть у товарища явно проблема во взаимодействии спецдрайвера с видеокартой (вероятно, при использовании не-generic управления), а Вы ему про жёсткий диск... Вы серьёзно? тем более что на generic-драйвере она работает.

Comment: @Денис Начните с проверки, хватает ли видеокарте питания (особенно, если у неё есть дополнительное подключение питания). Желательно пробовать с использованием заведомо исправного и гарантированно достаточно мощного блока питания, или отключить на время теста всё ненужное оборудование (лишние харды, сидюковод, карты расширения и пр.). Попробуйте протестировать видеокарту с любого LiveCD, где можно подключить "родной" драйвер. Попробуйте протестировать видеокарту в другом системном блоке.

Comment: Скажу так черный экран из-за видеокарты и её драйверов, если я удалю драйвера в безопасном режиме, то чёрный экран пропадает и я могу зайти в виндовс. А так он работает со встроенной видеокартой

Comment: @Akina, я написал возможные механические причины, конечно, я могу ошибаться, но " синий экран" возможен при данных проблемах. ))

Comment: @Arsen Автор говорит, что проблему синьки он устранил (уж не знаю насколько корректно). К тому же он, к сожалению, не рассказал, по какой причине систему сносило в синьку - а это как раз могло быть из-за видеодрайвера.

Comment: Наврятли он работал с бп уже долгое время и проблем не намичалось. Кроме как мышки Клавы монитора микрофона и колонок ничего не подключено

Comment: Хз, я просто играл, комп не включал весь день, думал изначально перегорела. Потом экран начал мерцать и за ним синий экран и так несколько раз. ну а после того черный экран

Comment: Зайти в безопастный режим, удалить новые драйвера для в/к, использовать те, что по умолчанию, или найти не очень новые для Windows 7. Потом пойти в магаз и купить nVidia карточку, а redeon продать и забыть )

Comment: Играл в кризис на пентиуме?))) Если не знаешь как тестить, то беги в сервисный. Надеюсь Биос ты сбрасывать пытался? Особенно если новый.

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд отвал чипа видеокарты. Т.е. от нагрева чип отпаивается от подложки.

Второй вариант, это помирает блок питания.

Попробуй поменять бп, видеокарту вставить в другой комп или погонять аиду на стабильность системы, смотря за графиками питания, можно ещё hwmonitor скачать, он всё показывает и тоже логи пишет.